# How to check all items when I click group title?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) to list all items. And I don't know how to receive the click event when I click the title of Group cell, which is generated by the ObjectListView.

I want to implement the function which checks (or unchecks) all items in the clicked group.

---

Edit:

I overcomed by add one button to check/uncheck the selected items. The ObjectListView will select all items of the clicked group, so I invoke the check/uncheck behavior by a button.

---

Edit:

The GroupTaskClicked event doesn't work. The version of ObjectListView is v2.6.0 (2012/10/20), with visual studio 2010.

Well, the GroupStateChanged event will fire, but it fires more than one time. I will explain more on my answer.

Comment: why you dont use ListViewItem?

Comment: I used ListView and it does not suit to my need.

Comment: may you tell me what you're trying to accomplished?because as long if only to get item selected based on its group, it's can accomplished with ListViewItem

Comment: Receiver the clicked event on the Group cell of ObjectListView. If I can receive the clicked event on the Group cell, then the following tasks can be done.

Comment: well. I dont't know how it's work in ObjectListView. But i guess it's the same with ListView. You should try look at SelectedIndexChages event, cause in ListView, when you click group in listview, and then SelectedItem properties will fill with items of those group.

Comment: Sorry, I think your suggestion doesn't help. The group cell is generated by ObjectListView, it should has a way to receive the touch event on the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GroupStateChanged will fire. I listen the event by following method.

```
 private void olvList_GroupStateChanged(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.GroupStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Name:" + e.Group.Header + "\r\nSelected:" + e.Group.Selected + "\r\nFocused:" + e.Focused + "\r\n");

        }
```

When I click a group cell, named "MyClickGroup", it will fire 2 events.

```
Name:MyClickGroup
Selected:True
Focused:False
Name:MyClickGroup
Selected:True
Focused:True
```

If I click a group cell named "MyNewGroup" while another cell named "MyClickGroup" was clicked first, it will fire 4 events.

```
Name:MyClickGroup
Selected:True
Focused:False
Name:MyClickGroup
Selected:False
Focused:False
Name:MyNewGroup
Selected:True
Focused:False
Name:MyNewGroup
Selected:True
Focused:True
```

So, the `GroupStateChanged` event , whose `Selected` and `Focused` state are `True`, means the selected and focused group cell currently. It is what I want about the clicked event on the group cell.